# Discordpy add an add_field to existing embed on command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to have a single embed that is going to be used as a list of some sort. I would like for an add_field to be added when a command is pushed to the bot. For example, I want to add to this current embed a new line with embed.add_field(name, value) that is given by a user when activated. How would I go about this? I've tried using message ID and message content but I don't think this is the best method. Thanks in advance.

```
@bot.command()
async def mangaEmbed(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = "Completed Self Prints",
        #description ="test",
        color = discord.Color.blue()
        )
    #embed.set_footer(text="Footer")
    #embed.set_image(url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/138231921925816320/902586759773306900/unknown.png?width=810&height=375")
    #embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/138231921925816320/902586759773306900/unknown.png?width=810&height=375")
    #embed.set_author(name= "Kyle G", icon_url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/138231921925816320/902586759773306900/unknown.png?width=810&height=375")
    embed.add_field(name="Kokou no Hito by NggKGG", value="Volumes 1-17", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="DrangonBall Z\nby NggKGG", value="Kokoue no 222o", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Homoculus", value="Volumes 1-24\nManmangaboy", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The new problem is not being able to pass the discord.Message using the message id

```
@bot.command()
async def editembed(ctx, vols, *, title):
    #just assuming you only want to get the first embed in the message
    message = discord.Message(903060490035556383)
    print(message)
    embed = message.embeds[0]
    embed.add_field(name=title, value=vols, inline=False)
    await message.edit(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to edit an already sent embed from a different command right?

`message` has the attribute `embeds`, which will return a list of embeds the message has. You can use that to get the embed you want and edit it in a separate command.
Something like this should work:

```py
@bot.command()
async def editembed(ctx, message: discord.Message):
    #just assuming you only want to get the first embed in the message
    embed = message.embeds[0]
    embed.add_field(name="test", value="test")
    await message.edit(embed=embed)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.embeds

Edit:

Regarding your second question:
You would have to get your message from somewhere, if it is always the same embed that you want to edit you can just define it inside your command using `fetch_message`. There are 2 ways to do this, either you would have to also get the channel the message you wanna edit is in, or just use `ctx` but then you can only use this command in the same channel as the embed that you want to edit.

Option 1 (recommended):

```py
@bot.command()
async def editembed(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(1234567890)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(1234567890)
```

Option 2:

```py
@bot.command()
async def editembed(ctx):
    message = await ctx.fetch_message(1234567890)
```

Please keep in mind that embeds can only have 25 fields in them though.

Comment: Thanks this is what I'm looking for, however, how would I be able to do it without having to type the message id in the command

Comment: @kgg I have edited my answer above, hope it helps you!